# LiveData from database not trigger Transformations.switchMap

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

Recently, I started merging my app into LiveData and Room.

After checking the document in android developer:

> [Transformations.switchMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations)

will be triggered whenever ***mAppPkgList*** changed.
When I inserted new record into database ***mAppPkgList*** changed, but ***Transformations.switchMap*** didn't trigger.

This is the implementation.

```
    ViewModel class
        public LiveData<List<Info>> mAppPkgList = new MutableLiveData<>(null);
        public LiveData<List<Info>> mAppList = Transformations.switchMap(mAppPkgList, list->{
            SLog.v(TAG,"Transformations.switchMap");
            List<Info> retArr = new ArrayList<>();
            //custom logic
            MutableLiveData<List<Info>> ret = new MutableLiveData<>();
            ret.setValue(retArr);
            return ret;
        });
    ...
    mAppPkgList  = appDAO.getInfo(id)
```

This is code in DAO.

```
@DAO
@Query("SELECT * from pkg WHERE id=:id")
    LiveData<List<Info>> getInfo(int id);
```

...

Could you help me trigger ***Transformations.switchMap*** whenever I insert new record into database ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to observe `mAppList` with an active observer.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce. I observered mAppList in activity already. model.mAppList.observer(activity, overver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to trigger mAppList whenever a new row gets inserted into the table, you would have to observe the whole table content like:

Dao:

`@Query("SELECT * FROM pkg")
 fun getAllInfos(): LiveData<List<Info>>`

ViewModel:

`val allInfos = appDAO.getAllInfos()
val mAppList = Transformations.switchMap(allInfos, { infos -> ... })`

This way mAppList will always get triggered, if the table content changes (new rows added/removed or modified)